# How do you create a deployment configuration in OpenShift? Is it automatic for new-app based on a docker image?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm creating a new-app based on an image stream that corresponds to a docker image in a private OpenShift docker registry. The command is:

```
oc new-app mynamespace/my-image:latest -n=my-project
```

*Question 1*: Does this command automatically create a deployment configuration (dc) that can be referrenced as `dc/my-image`? Is this deployment configuration associated with `my-project`?

*Question 2*: What is the oc command to create a deployment configuration? The OpenShift developer guide has a section titled [Creating a Deployment Configuration](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/deployments.html#creating-a-deployment-configuration), but surprisingly it does **not** say how to create a DC or give any examples. It just shows a JSON structure and says DCs can be managed with the `oc` command.

Comment: It's a few months ago I used OpenShift and I know it's changing frequently. But normally the `oc new-app` command creates a DC which contains  the setup of pod, of a replication controller (or replica set) and the setup of a service above your container (pod). So it will create a pod in the right project with a service above and with a RC (to scale up/down). You can check or change your deployment with `oc edit dc` and add specifc futures. (or use commands as `oc scale` (scale up) to change the configuration. You can export the DC as a .json/.yaml and recreate it on othr places w `oc create`

Comment: The most common way I used it was using `oc new-app` and create routes above the service with `oc expose svc`, change the scalement of the pod with `oc scale` etc. and than export the whole configuration (DC) as .yaml or .json. So doing manual steps to create your final DC. After some time you'll be more experienced and probably able to write your own. We stored the .yaml and .json files so it was easy to recreate our setup with `oc create -f our-dc.yaml`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your command will create stuff in the specified project. You can check what objects are created using the `oc get` command. i.e. to check what DCs you have, you'd do `oc get dc` or `oc get deploymentconfigs`.

Other useful commands are `oc describe` - similar to `get` but more information. `oc status -v` - see more broad information about project including warnings and errors.

You create DC and any other resource types using the `oc create` command. e.g. you copy the example DC off the URL you link to and put it into a file. Finally you do `oc create -f mydc.yaml`. Both YAML and JSON are supported.

As you see some commands can create DCs by themselves without you providing them with YAML or JSON. You can later modify existing resources with `oc edit service/my-app`. There is the `oc patch` command suitable for scripting.

You can see existing resource YAML doing `oc get dc/myds -o yaml`. Same with any other resource. Keep in mind you are presently using the desired project or use the `-n` option as you are doing in your example.

Not that hard once you understand some basics and learn to use the `oc describe` and `oc logs` command to debug issues with your images/pods. e.g. `oc describe pod/my-app-1-asdfg`, `oc logs my-app-1-asdfg`, `oc logs -f dc/my-app`.

HTH